# A crypto-limerick

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle, limerick

> If you AES the last line,
>   With a key made of something divine,
>   And then you XOR
>   The SHA-1 of "4",
>   FWqY58QhWVqPDX0uQ8C37AYaPeWFab42F2nyuY+zWK/gCV2bo8hIDt6sjon1I8+Y64RzJcCwlHIouiebHza67ErpHbVVWeZh4Pf8GBVtrDU=

Can you figure out what the "divine thing" is and then follow the instructions to determine what the keyword hidden in the last line of this limerick is?

---

Important hint:

> The AES key is a word padded with null characters at the end to make it 16 bytes total.

Comment: purely aes or also an operation mode like cbc?

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to mention, it's AES ECB, like you're probably thinking. Nothing fancy.

Comment: 128 bit aes? :p

Comment: AES is always 128-bit unless specified otherwise. (At least, I _think_ that's the convention...)

Comment: Although honestly, it's not like you'd get any answer that made sense if you used a block size *other* than 128 bits, if the last line was indeed encrypted using a 128-bit block size...

Comment: Well there are 3 sizes, 128, 192, 256. 128 is common but not that much more than 256. Though yes usually when people say aes they mean 128, just checking ;) i've also figured out it is nit easy to do this on a phone so i'll try tomorrow, p.s. Does the thing happen to be divine and home made? ;)

Comment: The first line doesn't have the proper cadence for a limerick. :(

Comment: @IanMacDonald Neither does the last line :p

Comment: @IanMacDonald If you stress the "S", then the cadence works. I think. Like: "If **you** AE**S** this last **line**".

Comment: @IanMacDonald I actually had it as "the" at first, but then I shadow-edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key (before null padding) is

> God

After properly decoded, AESed and XORed the last line is

> `You'll find that the answer is 'brine'.\x00You'll find that the answer is 'brine'.\x00

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, i just wanted to create some activity

Well.. after a long talk with the OP i figured out the following:

With a key made of something divine,

> GOD, god is something divine (obviously)

Sha-1 of 4

> 1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a

The last line

> now if you AES this line with god (encrypt or decrypt) rubbish comes out, XOR this with the hash of 4 and it still makes no sense.

I'm just too stupid to follow simple instructions, it's a miracle my house isn't on fire yet :P

Comment: I can tell you, the divine thing is not a soul.

Comment: Also, the base 64 encoding is just to transcribe encrypted binary data. You need to apply all the ciphers to the bytes of the last line.

Comment: Thirdly, notice that the SHA-1 of 4 is only a fifth of the length of the line. You may need to repeat the key multiple times.

Comment: @JoeZ. use all the ciphers on the last line? do you know how many ciphers there are in the world? :P I'll never get them all ;)

Comment: All the ciphers mentioned in the question, i.e. the AES and the XOR.

Comment: @JoeZ. yeh i figured :P could you give a hint as to how many characters the divine something has?

Comment: @JoeZ. is it man? "in pagan stories man is made from something divine,"

Comment: @JoeZ. Woman? well oke i guess that could be true

Comment: @JoeZ. that is also an option xD sorry but it can be interpeted so many ways

Comment: By the key being "made of" something divine, I meant that it was padded using the algorithm in the spoiler.

Comment: You're not using the right key, obviously. How are you inputting the AES key?

Comment: Oh, I see it in the spoiler. No, I didn't say pad it with zeros, I said pad it with null characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23157/discussion-between-vincent-advocaat-and-joe-z).